# Google API call from TypeScript client side only

Tags: typescript, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, jwt

I'm making PoC to use google spreadsheet as an backend and google itself as an auth service.

So the steps is:

- Google auth user on static js website via https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-jwt
- Get some sort of token and use https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets
- ...
- Profit

Right now, year 2023 some of the OAuth is about to be... deprecated (yes, google) and I'm confused what is going on. Is it possible to just auth user, save token to `localStorage` and using this token work with another google services, like sheets.

I've tried to put JWT token in the header - no result.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you provide your existing code with the error you have encountered? Also please provide a dummy sheet to work on with your desired output.